# karaf configuration property is garbled

Tags: character-encoding, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I implement org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService interface to get Karaf configuration. But when I give a Chinese value to the property, it is garbled.Initially, the files in the etc folder are encoded in latin1. I have tried to set utf-8 encoding, but it has no effect. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

In Karaf, the configurations files (ie `etc/*.cfg`) are handled by the felix subproject "fileinstall".

fileinstall doesn't support yet to specified a custom character encoding for the configuration, it uses the `Properties` class and `Properties.load(InputStream)`, which documents:

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store
>   properties from and to a character based stream in a simple
>   line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) /
>   store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the
>   load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, **except the input/output
>   stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding**. Characters that
>   cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using
>   Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language
>   Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape
>   sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files
>   to and from other character encodings.

So, you have to encode your file in ISE-8859-1 and quote every UTF character,  or use an xml file to encode your configuration files.

Comment: Thank you very much,Jérémie B.That is the point.I change the file to ISO 8859-1 character encoding. And Then convert Chinese words to Unicode format.It runs all right now.Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jérémie B. You saved a lot of my time!

Comment: The same concept affects Apache Felix OSGi .

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to change cfg files encoding.
Configuration for fileinstall subproject polling etc/*.cfg files is written in config.properties file.
You can add

```
felix.fileinstall.configEncoding = UTF-8
```

The solution was checked in Karaf 4